# Drupal8 composer league/csv and swiftmailer conflict or minimum-stability

Tags: configuration, composer-php, updates, export-to-csv, drupal-8

I try to use this command in my drupal8 root folder:

```
~/web$ php ../composer.phar drupal-update -dev
```

In my composer.json file I have:

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
    "league/csv": "^8.1@dev",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4@dev"
},
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "~8.1",
    "drupal/csv_serialization": "8.*",
    "drupal/pathauto": "8.*",
    "drupal/swiftmailer": "8.*"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": false,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
...
```

When I try this command I have this error:

```
Problem 1
- The requested package league/csv ^7.1 is satisfiable by league/csv[7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 2
- The requested package swiftmailer/swiftmailer 5.2.*@stable is satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

On many page found here and there, they said to put my minimum-stability to "dev" but nothing change.

When I try to update, remove or anything... I have this error.

If you know what I do wrong, I will be extremely grateful for the time you are taking for me.

In advance, thank you very much!

P.s. Forgive me for my terrible English

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way that composer handles dependencies you will need to edit your **composer.json** file and downgrade two of your dependencies in order for this to work.

Example:

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
    "league/csv": "^7.2",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.2"
},
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "~8.1",
    "drupal/csv_serialization": "8.*",
    "drupal/pathauto": "8.*",
    "drupal/swiftmailer": "8.*"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": false,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
```